# typeorm leftjoins and suquery alias is not fund

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

i want to filter users based on brand ids but i get error `TypeORMError: "b" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?`

how can i achieve the subquery using the previous aliases or a way to add it again?

```js
        this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
          .leftJoin('user.brand', 'b')
          .leftJoin('user.companies', 'c')
          .select(['user.id', 'user.name', 'user.role', 'user.email', 'user.activated', 'b', 'c'])
          .andWhere('user.role = "ROLE_ADVERTISER"')
          .andWhere((qb) => {
            const subQuery = qb
              .subQuery()
              .select('brand', 'b')
              .leftJoin('b.company', 'c')
              .where('c.id = :cid', { cid: 2 })
              .getQuery()
            return 'b.id IN' + subQuery;
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
          .leftJoin('user.brand', 'b')
          .leftJoin('user.companies', 'c')
          .select(['user.id', 'user.name', 'user.role', 'user.email', 'user.activated', 'b', 'c'])
          .andWhere('user.role = "ROLE_ADVERTISER"')
          .orWhere((subQuery) => {
            return 'b.id IN' +
              subQuery
                .subQuery()
                .from(BrandEntity, 'b')
                .leftJoin('b.company', 'c')
                .select("b.id")
                .where('c.id = :cid', { cid: 2 })
                .getQuery()
          });
```

this works!